# How extract an appropriate mean from a posterior distribution

Tags: variational-bayes

I am studying deterministic inference algorithms to learn posterior probability of Gaussian distributions and we need to find the hyperparameters for the mean and variance random variables of the posterior after we observe our training data.

So, how we set the exact value for the mean and precision of the posterior distribution after the hyperparameters are trained and inferred? Do we need to put their mean values?

Comment: The question is unclear: what is a "posterior probability of Gaussian distributions"? what does "find the hyperparameters [from] training data" mean? This is not a Bayesian modelling if it depends on the data. I suggest reading the W. entry on [empirical Bayes methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_Bayes_method).

Comment: Do you know how to initialize the first Ƴ at VMP for the single Gaussian?

Comment: What does this mean?!

Answer (score 0):

This is the variational message passing inference algorithm to infer a Gaussian mean and precision after observing some data of that Gaussian distribution.
http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume6/winn05a/winn05a.pdf